# Is it necessary to include a blank line at the end of .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers

I am reading a few different .htaccess tutorials and finding this requirement that I have never heard before:

> Then make sure you have one blank line at the bottom of your .htaccess
>   file, otherwise you will get a Malformed Header message.

And from another source:

> Once you have inserted the commands to 301 redirect your pages, you
>   need to make sure that there is a blank line at the end of the file.
>   Your server will read the .htaccess file line by line, which means at
>   some point you’ll need to throw them an “endline” character to let
>   them know you’re finished. An easy way to do this is to put a blank
>   line at the bottom of the file.

I have never included a blank line at the end of my .htaccess files and am unaware of any header errors on any of my sites.

Is the blank line really required?

Comment: Never done this before. I don't see the problem if you woudn't

Comment: Why don't you read official docs? :)

Comment: I've never intentionally have done that before either.

Comment: Whoever wrote that doesn’t seem to know what they are talking about. Don’t believe everything you find “somewhere on the internet” – stick to the official documentation instead. (And that doesn’t mention anything like this.)